# How to Get Harddisk SerialNo for windows 2003 Server Sp2 using WMI

Tags: vb.net

THis code below retrived Hdd SerialNumber.it works both on windows Xp and windows 7.But does not work on Windows 2003 Server SP2.Please any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub GetSerialWin()
    Dim strServer = "."
    Dim objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strServer & "/root\cimv2")
    ' Dim objInstances = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMedia", 48)
    Dim objInstances = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMedia")
    'On Error Resume Next
    Try
        For Each objInstance In objInstances

          MsgBox(objInstance.SerialNumber.ToString)

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do on 2k3? Does it generate any errors? Does it return nothing? Does it return incomplete results? Does it return incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

#### WMIUtil

```
public static class WMIUtil
{
    public const string Account = "Win32_Account";
    public const string AccountSID = "Win32_AccountSID";
    public const string ACE = "Win32_ACE";
    public const string ActionCheck = "Win32_ActionCheck";
    public const string AllocatedResource = "Win32_AllocatedResource";
    public const string ApplicationCommandLine = "Win32_ApplicationCommandLine";
    public const string ApplicationService = "Win32_ApplicationService";
    public const string AssociatedBattery = "Win32_AssociatedBattery";
    public const string AssociatedProcessorMemory = "Win32_AssociatedProcessorMemory";
    public const string BaseBoard = "Win32_BaseBoard";
    public const string BaseService = "Win32_BaseService";
    public const string Battery = "Win32_Battery";
    public const string Binary = "Win32_Binary";
    public const string BindImageAction = "Win32_BindImageAction";
    public const string BIOS = "Win32_BIOS";
    public const string BootConfiguration = "Win32_BootConfiguration";
    public const string Bus = "Win32_Bus";
    public const string CacheMemory = "Win32_CacheMemory";
    public const string CDROMDrive = "Win32_CDROMDrive";
    public const string CheckCheck = "Win32_CheckCheck";
    public const string CIMLogicalDeviceCIMDataFile = "Win32_CIMLogicalDeviceCIMDataFile";
    public const string ClassicCOMApplicationClasses = "Win32_ClassicCOMApplicationClasses";
    public const string ClassicCOMClass = "Win32_ClassicCOMClass";
    public const string ClassicCOMClassSetting = "Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting";
    public const string ClassicCOMClassSettings = "Win32_ClassicCOMClassSettings";
    public const string ClassInfoAction = "Win32_ClassInfoAction";
    public const string ClientApplicationSetting = "Win32_ClientApplicationSetting";
    public const string CodecFile = "Win32_CodecFile";
    public const string COMApplication = "Win32_COMApplication";
    public const string COMApplicationClasses = "Win32_COMApplicationClasses";
    public const string COMApplicationSettings = "Win32_COMApplicationSettings";
    public const string COMClass = "Win32_COMClass";
    public const string ComClassAutoEmulator = "Win32_ComClassAutoEmulator";
    public const string ComClassEmulator = "Win32_ComClassEmulator";
    public const string CommandLineAccess = "Win32_CommandLineAccess";
    public const string ComponentCategory = "Win32_ComponentCategory";
    public const string ComputerSystem = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
    public const string ComputerSystemProcessor = "Win32_ComputerSystemProcessor";
    public const string ComputerSystemProduct = "Win32_ComputerSystemProduct";
    public const string COMSetting = "Win32_COMSetting";
    public const string Condition = "Win32_Condition";
    public const string CreateFolderAction = "Win32_CreateFolderAction";
    public const string CurrentProbe = "Win32_CurrentProbe";
    public const string DCOMApplication = "Win32_DCOMApplication";
    public const string DCOMApplicationAccessAllowedSetting = "Win32_DCOMApplicationAccessAllowedSetting";
    public const string DCOMApplicationLaunchAllowedSetting = "Win32_DCOMApplicationLaunchAllowedSetting";
    public const string DCOMApplicationSetting = "Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting";
    public const string DependentService = "Win32_DependentService";
    public const string Desktop = "Win32_Desktop";
    public const string DesktopMonitor = "Win32_DesktopMonitor";
    public const string DeviceBus = "Win32_DeviceBus";
    public const string DeviceMemoryAddress = "Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress";
    public const string DeviceSettings = "Win32_DeviceSettings";
    public const string Directory = "Win32_Directory";
    public const string DirectorySpecification = "Win32_DirectorySpecification";
    public const string DiskDrive = "Win32_DiskDrive";
    public const string DiskDriveToDiskPartition = "Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
    public const string DiskPartition = "Win32_DiskPartition";
    public const string DisplayConfiguration = "Win32_DisplayConfiguration";
    public const string DisplayControllerConfiguration = "Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration";
    public const string DMAChannel = "Win32_DMAChannel";
    public const string DriverVXD = "Win32_DriverVXD";
    public const string DuplicateFileAction = "Win32_DuplicateFileAction";
    public const string Environment = "Win32_Environment";
    public const string EnvironmentSpecification = "Win32_EnvironmentSpecification";
    public const string ExtensionInfoAction = "Win32_ExtensionInfoAction";
    public const string Fan = "Win32_Fan";
    public const string FileSpecification = "Win32_FileSpecification";
    public const string Firewire1394Controller = "Win32_1394Controller";
    public const string Firewire1394ControllerDevice = "Win32_1394ControllerDevice";
    public const string FloppyController = "Win32_FloppyController";
    public const string FloppyDrive = "Win32_FloppyDrive";
    public const string FontInfoAction = "Win32_FontInfoAction";
    public const string Group = "Win32_Group";
    public const string GroupUser = "Win32_GroupUser";
    public const string HeatPipe = "Win32_HeatPipe";
    public const string IDEController = "Win32_IDEController";
    public const string IDEControllerDevice = "Win32_IDEControllerDevice";
    public const string ImplementedCategory = "Win32_ImplementedCategory";
    public const string InfraredDevice = "Win32_InfraredDevice";
    public const string IniFileSpecification = "Win32_IniFileSpecification";
    public const string InstalledSoftwareElement = "Win32_InstalledSoftwareElement";
    public const string IRQResource = "Win32_IRQResource";
    public const string Keyboard = "Win32_Keyboard";
    public const string LaunchCondition = "Win32_LaunchCondition";
    public const string LoadOrderGroup = "Win32_LoadOrderGroup";
    public const string LoadOrderGroupServiceDependencies = "Win32_LoadOrderGroupServiceDependencies";
    public const string LoadOrderGroupServiceMembers = "Win32_LoadOrderGroupServiceMembers";
    public const string LogicalDisk = "Win32_LogicalDisk";
    public const string LogicalDiskRootDirectory = "Win32_LogicalDiskRootDirectory";
    public const string LogicalDiskToPartition = "Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
    public const string LogicalFileAccess = "Win32_LogicalFileAccess";
    public const string LogicalFileAuditing = "Win32_LogicalFileAuditing";
    public const string LogicalFileGroup = "Win32_LogicalFileGroup";
    public const string LogicalFileOwner = "Win32_LogicalFileOwner";
    public const string LogicalFileSecuritySetting = "Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting";
    public const string LogicalMemoryConfiguration = "Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration";
    public const string LogicalProgramGroup = "Win32_LogicalProgramGroup";
    public const string LogicalProgramGroupDirectory = "Win32_LogicalProgramGroupDirectory";
    public const string LogicalProgramGroupItem = "Win32_LogicalProgramGroupItem";
    public const string LogicalProgramGroupItemDataFile = "Win32_LogicalProgramGroupItemDataFile";
    public const string LogicalShareAccess = "Win32_LogicalShareAccess";
    public const string LogicalShareAuditing = "Win32_LogicalShareAuditing";
    public const string LogicalShareSecuritySetting = "Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting";
    public const string ManagedSystemElementResource = "Win32_ManagedSystemElementResource";
    public const string MemoryArray = "Win32_MemoryArray";
    public const string MemoryArrayLocation = "Win32_MemoryArrayLocation";
    public const string MemoryDevice = "Win32_MemoryDevice";
    public const string MemoryDeviceArray = "Win32_MemoryDeviceArray";
    public const string MemoryDeviceLocation = "Win32_MemoryDeviceLocation";
    public const string MethodParameterClass = "Win32_MethodParameterClass";
    public const string MIMEInfoAction = "Win32_MIMEInfoAction";
    public const string MotherboardDevice = "Win32_MotherboardDevice";
    public const string MoveFileAction = "Win32_MoveFileAction";
    public const string MSIResource = "Win32_MSIResource";
    public const string NetworkAdapter = "Win32_NetworkAdapter";
    public const string NetworkAdapterConfiguration = "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration";
    public const string NetworkAdapterSetting = "Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting";
    public const string NetworkClient = "Win32_NetworkClient";
    public const string NetworkConnection = "Win32_NetworkConnection";
    public const string NetworkLoginProfile = "Win32_NetworkLoginProfile";
    public const string NetworkProtocol = "Win32_NetworkProtocol";
    public const string NTEventlogFile = "Win32_NTEventlogFile";
    public const string NTLogEvent = "Win32_NTLogEvent";
    public const string NTLogEventComputer = "Win32_NTLogEventComputer";
    public const string NTLogEventLog = "Win32_NTLogEventLog";
    public const string NTLogEventUser = "Win32_NTLogEventUser";
    public const string ODBCAttribute = "Win32_ODBCAttribute";
    public const string ODBCDataSourceAttribute = "Win32_ODBCDataSourceAttribute";
    public const string ODBCDataSourceSpecification = "Win32_ODBCDataSourceSpecification";
    public const string ODBCDriverAttribute = "Win32_ODBCDriverAttribute";
    public const string ODBCDriverSoftwareElement = "Win32_ODBCDriverSoftwareElement";
    public const string ODBCDriverSpecification = "Win32_ODBCDriverSpecification";
    public const string ODBCSourceAttribute = "Win32_ODBCSourceAttribute";
    public const string ODBCTranslatorSpecification = "Win32_ODBCTranslatorSpecification";
    public const string OnBoardDevice = "Win32_OnBoardDevice";
    public const string OperatingSystem = "Win32_OperatingSystem";
    public const string OperatingSystemQFE = "Win32_OperatingSystemQFE";
    public const string OSRecoveryConfiguration = "Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguration";
    public const string PageFile = "Win32_PageFile";
    public const string PageFileElementSetting = "Win32_PageFileElementSetting";
    public const string PageFileSetting = "Win32_PageFileSetting";
    public const string PageFileUsage = "Win32_PageFileUsage";
    public const string ParallelPort = "Win32_ParallelPort";
    public const string Patch = "Win32_Patch";
    public const string PatchFile = "Win32_PatchFile";
    public const string PatchPackage = "Win32_PatchPackage";
    public const string PCMCIAController = "Win32_PCMCIAController";
    public const string Perf = "Win32_Perf";
    public const string PerfRawData = "Win32_PerfRawData";
    public const string PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages = "Win32_PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages";
    public const string PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETAppsv114322 = "Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETAppsv114322";
    public const string PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETv114322 = "Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETv114322";
    public const string PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET = "Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET";
    public const string PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications = "Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications";
    public const string PerfRawData_IAS_IASAccountingClients = "Win32_PerfRawData_IAS_IASAccountingClients";
    public const string PerfRawData_IAS_IASAccountingServer = "Win32_PerfRawData_IAS_IASAccountingServer";
    public const string PerfRawData_IAS_IASAuthenticationClients = "Win32_PerfRawData_IAS_IASAuthenticationClients";
    public const string PerfRawData_IAS_IASAuthenticationServer = "Win32_PerfRawData_IAS_IASAuthenticationServer";
    public const string PerfRawData_InetInfo_InternetInformationServicesGlobal = "Win32_PerfRawData_InetInfo_InternetInformationServicesGlobal";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSDTC_DistributedTransactionCoordinator = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSDTC_DistributedTransactionCoordinator";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSFTPSVC_FTPService = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSFTPSVC_FTPService";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerAccessMethods = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerAccessMethods";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBackupDevice = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBackupDevice";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBufferManager = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBufferManager";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBufferPartition = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerBufferPartition";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerCacheManager = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerCacheManager";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerDatabases = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerDatabases";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerGeneralStatistics = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerGeneralStatistics";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerLatches = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerLatches";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerLocks = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerLocks";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerMemoryManager = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerMemoryManager";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationAgents = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationAgents";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationDist = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationDist";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationLogreader = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationLogreader";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationMerge = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationMerge";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationSnapshot = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerReplicationSnapshot";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerSQLStatistics = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerSQLStatistics";
    public const string PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerUserSettable = "Win32_PerfRawData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerUserSettable";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRInterop = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRInterop";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRJit = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRJit";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLoading = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLoading";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLocksAndThreads = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLocksAndThreads";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRRemoting = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRRemoting";
    public const string PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity = "Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity";
    public const string PerfRawData_Outlook_Outlook = "Win32_PerfRawData_Outlook_Outlook";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfNet_Browser = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Browser";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfNet_Redirector = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Redirector";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfNet_ServerWorkQueues = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_ServerWorkQueues";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_Cache = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Cache";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_Objects = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Objects";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_PagingFile = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_PagingFile";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfOS_System = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_System";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_FullImage_Costly = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_FullImage_Costly";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_Image_Costly = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Image_Costly";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObject = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObject";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObjectDetails = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObjectDetails";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_ProcessAddressSpace_Costly = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_ProcessAddressSpace_Costly";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_Thread = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Thread";
    public const string PerfRawData_PerfProc_ThreadDetails_Costly = "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_ThreadDetails_Costly";
    public const string PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASPort = "Win32_PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASPort";
    public const string PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASTotal = "Win32_PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASTotal";
    public const string PerfRawData_RSVP_ACSPerRSVPService = "Win32_PerfRawData_RSVP_ACSPerRSVPService";
    public const string PerfRawData_Spooler_PrintQueue = "Win32_PerfRawData_Spooler_PrintQueue";
    public const string PerfRawData_TapiSrv_Telephony = "Win32_PerfRawData_TapiSrv_Telephony";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_ICMP = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_ICMP";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_IP = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_IP";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_NBTConnection = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NBTConnection";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_TCP = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_TCP";
    public const string PerfRawData_Tcpip_UDP = "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_UDP";
    public const string PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService = "Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService";
    public const string PhysicalMemory = "Win32_PhysicalMemory";
    public const string PhysicalMemoryArray = "Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray";
    public const string PhysicalMemoryLocation = "Win32_PhysicalMemoryLocation";
    public const string PNPAllocatedResource = "Win32_PNPAllocatedResource";
    public const string PnPDevice = "Win32_PnPDevice";
    public const string PnPEntity = "Win32_PnPEntity";
    public const string PointingDevice = "Win32_PointingDevice";
    public const string PortableBattery = "Win32_PortableBattery";
    public const string PortConnector = "Win32_PortConnector";
    public const string PortResource = "Win32_PortResource";
    public const string POTSModem = "Win32_POTSModem";
    public const string POTSModemToSerialPort = "Win32_POTSModemToSerialPort";
    public const string PowerManagementEvent = "Win32_PowerManagementEvent";
    public const string Printer = "Win32_Printer";
    public const string PrinterConfiguration = "Win32_PrinterConfiguration";
    public const string PrinterController = "Win32_PrinterController";
    public const string PrinterDriverDll = "Win32_PrinterDriverDll";
    public const string PrinterSetting = "Win32_PrinterSetting";
    public const string PrinterShare = "Win32_PrinterShare";
    public const string PrintJob = "Win32_PrintJob";
    public const string PrivilegesStatus = "Win32_PrivilegesStatus";
    public const string Process = "Win32_Process";
    public const string Processor = "Win32_Processor";
    public const string ProcessStartup = "Win32_ProcessStartup";
    public const string Product = "Win32_Product";
    public const string ProductCheck = "Win32_ProductCheck";
    public const string ProductResource = "Win32_ProductResource";
    public const string ProductSoftwareFeatures = "Win32_ProductSoftwareFeatures";
    public const string ProgIDSpecification = "Win32_ProgIDSpecification";
    public const string ProgramGroup = "Win32_ProgramGroup";
    public const string ProgramGroupContents = "Win32_ProgramGroupContents";
    public const string ProgramGroupOrItem = "Win32_ProgramGroupOrItem";
    public const string Property = "Win32_Property";
    public const string ProtocolBinding = "Win32_ProtocolBinding";
    public const string PublishComponentAction = "Win32_PublishComponentAction";
    public const string QuickFixEngineering = "Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
    public const string Refrigeration = "Win32_Refrigeration";
    public const string Registry = "Win32_Registry";
    public const string RegistryAction = "Win32_RegistryAction";
    public const string RemoveFileAction = "Win32_RemoveFileAction";
    public const string RemoveIniAction = "Win32_RemoveIniAction";
    public const string ReserveCost = "Win32_ReserveCost";
    public const string ScheduledJob = "Win32_ScheduledJob";
    public const string SCSIController = "Win32_SCSIController";
    public const string SCSIControllerDevice = "Win32_SCSIControllerDevice";
    public const string SecurityDescriptor = "Win32_SecurityDescriptor";
    public const string SecuritySetting = "Win32_SecuritySetting";
    public const string SecuritySettingAccess = "Win32_SecuritySettingAccess";
    public const string SecuritySettingAuditing = "Win32_SecuritySettingAuditing";
    public const string SecuritySettingGroup = "Win32_SecuritySettingGroup";
    public const string SecuritySettingOfLogicalFile = "Win32_SecuritySettingOfLogicalFile";
    public const string SecuritySettingOfLogicalShare = "Win32_SecuritySettingOfLogicalShare";
    public const string SecuritySettingOfObject = "Win32_SecuritySettingOfObject";
    public const string SecuritySettingOwner = "Win32_SecuritySettingOwner";
    public const string SelfRegModuleAction = "Win32_SelfRegModuleAction";
    public const string SerialPort = "Win32_SerialPort";
    public const string SerialPortConfiguration = "Win32_SerialPortConfiguration";
    public const string SerialPortSetting = "Win32_SerialPortSetting";
    public const string Service = "Win32_Service";
    public const string ServiceControl = "Win32_ServiceControl";
    public const string ServiceSpecification = "Win32_ServiceSpecification";
    public const string ServiceSpecificationService = "Win32_ServiceSpecificationService";
    public const string SettingCheck = "Win32_SettingCheck";
    public const string Share = "Win32_Share";
    public const string ShareToDirectory = "Win32_ShareToDirectory";
    public const string ShortcutAction = "Win32_ShortcutAction";
    public const string ShortcutFile = "Win32_ShortcutFile";
    public const string ShortcutSAP = "Win32_ShortcutSAP";
    public const string SID = "Win32_SID";
    public const string SMBIOSMemory = "Win32_SMBIOSMemory";
    public const string SoftwareElement = "Win32_SoftwareElement";
    public const string SoftwareElementAction = "Win32_SoftwareElementAction";
    public const string SoftwareElementCheck = "Win32_SoftwareElementCheck";
    public const string SoftwareElementCondition = "Win32_SoftwareElementCondition";
    public const string SoftwareElementResource = "Win32_SoftwareElementResource";
    public const string SoftwareFeature = "Win32_SoftwareFeature";
    public const string SoftwareFeatureAction = "Win32_SoftwareFeatureAction";
    public const string SoftwareFeatureCheck = "Win32_SoftwareFeatureCheck";
    public const string SoftwareFeatureParent = "Win32_SoftwareFeatureParent";
    public const string SoftwareFeatureSoftwareElements = "Win32_SoftwareFeatureSoftwareElements";
    public const string SoundDevice = "Win32_SoundDevice";
    public const string StartupCommand = "Win32_StartupCommand";
    public const string SubDirectory = "Win32_SubDirectory";
    public const string SystemAccount = "Win32_SystemAccount";
    public const string SystemBIOS = "Win32_SystemBIOS";
    public const string SystemBootConfiguration = "Win32_SystemBootConfiguration";
    public const string SystemDesktop = "Win32_SystemDesktop";
    public const string SystemDevices = "Win32_SystemDevices";
    public const string SystemDriver = "Win32_SystemDriver";
    public const string SystemDriverPNPEntity = "Win32_SystemDriverPNPEntity";
    public const string SystemEnclosure = "Win32_SystemEnclosure";
    public const string SystemLoadOrderGroups = "Win32_SystemLoadOrderGroups";
    public const string SystemLogicalMemoryConfiguration = "Win32_SystemLogicalMemoryConfiguration";
    public const string SystemMemoryResource = "Win32_SystemMemoryResource";
    public const string SystemNetworkConnections = "Win32_SystemNetworkConnections";
    public const string SystemOperatingSystem = "Win32_SystemOperatingSystem";
    public const string SystemPartitions = "Win32_SystemPartitions";
    public const string SystemProcesses = "Win32_SystemProcesses";
    public const string SystemProgramGroups = "Win32_SystemProgramGroups";
    public const string SystemResources = "Win32_SystemResources";
    public const string SystemServices = "Win32_SystemServices";
    public const string SystemSetting = "Win32_SystemSetting";
    public const string SystemSlot = "Win32_SystemSlot";
    public const string SystemSystemDriver = "Win32_SystemSystemDriver";
    public const string SystemTimeZone = "Win32_SystemTimeZone";
    public const string SystemUsers = "Win32_SystemUsers";
    public const string TapeDrive = "Win32_TapeDrive";
    public const string TemperatureProbe = "Win32_TemperatureProbe";
    public const string Thread = "Win32_Thread";
    public const string TimeZone = "Win32_TimeZone";
    public const string Trustee = "Win32_Trustee";
    public const string TypeLibraryAction = "Win32_TypeLibraryAction";
    public const string UninterruptiblePowerSupply = "Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply";
    public const string USBController = "Win32_USBController";
    public const string USBControllerDevice = "Win32_USBControllerDevice";
    public const string UserAccount = "Win32_UserAccount";
    public const string UserDesktop = "Win32_UserDesktop";
    public const string VideoConfiguration = "Win32_VideoConfiguration";
    public const string VideoController = "Win32_VideoController";
    public const string VideoSettings = "Win32_VideoSettings";
    public const string VoltageProbe = "Win32_VoltageProbe";
    public const string WMIElementSetting = "Win32_WMIElementSetting";
    public const string WMISetting = "Win32_WMISetting";

    public static Dictionary<string, object> Search(string key)
    {
    return AdvancedSearch(key).SelectMany(o => o.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>()).ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);
    }

    public static KeyValuePair<string, object>? Search(string key, string propertyName)
    {
    ManagementObject item = AdvancedSearch(key, propertyName);
    PropertyData data = null;

    if (item != null && (data = item.Properties[propertyName]) != null)
        return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(data.Name, data.Value);

    return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ManagementObject> AdvancedSearch(string key)
    {
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM {0}".FormatString(key));

    foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
        yield return item;
    }

    public static ManagementObject AdvancedSearch(string key, string propertyName)
    {
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT {0} FROM {1}".FormatString(propertyName, key));
    ManagementObjectCollection items = searcher.Get();

    if (!items.IsNullOrEmpty())
        return items.Cast<ManagementObject>().First();

    return null;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
KeyValuePair<string, object>? property = WMIUtil.Search(WMIUtil.Processor, "ProcessorId");

if (property.HasValue)
    return property.Value.Value;
```